# How to summarize data with duplicate rows

Tags: r

I have this `data.frame`:

```
> head(people)
    role name           n
1   A    Chet Baker     1
2   A    Chet Baker     2
3   A    Miles Davis    2
4   B    Miles Davis    5
5   A    Miles Davis    1
6   A    Bill Evans     1
```

The data is messy because it didn't summarize correctly the values, generating duplicates for the same information.

I need two `data.frame`s.

One like this:

```
> head(sum_people)
    name           n
1   Chet Baker     3
2   Miles Davis    8
3   Bill Evans     1
```

containing the total of times one appeared in the df with its `n`

and another one like this:

```
> head(sum_people_role)
    role name           n
1   A    Chet Baker     3
2   A    Miles Davis    3
3   B    Miles Davis    
4   A    Bill Evans     1
```

Containing the totals whith the role specified.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: so `aggregate(n~name, people, length)` and `aggregate(n~name+role, people, length)` ?

Comment: ive tried using the `agreggate` function with the columns but it didn't work

Comment: Why didn't it work? Replace `length` with `sum` in @RonakShah's answer, i.e. `aggregate(n~name, people, sum)`.

Answer (score 1):

These are easy operations using the `dplyr`-package.

```
library(dplyr)

sum_people <- people %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% summarise(n=sum(n))
sum_people_role <- people %>% 
  group_by(name, role) %>% summarise(n=sum(n))
```

The `%>%` operator is a daisy-chaining operator. Without it, the above could be written as:

```
sum_people <- summarise(group_by(.data=people, name), n=sum(n))
```

and for longer operations using imaginary functions `f`, `g` and `h`, we could write it old-fashioned:

```
step1 <- f(data, arg1=5)
step2 <- g(step1, arg2=0, na.rm=TRUE)
result <- h(step2)
```

or less verbose

```
result <- h(g(f(data, arg1=5), arg2=0, na.rm=TRUE))
```

or daisy-chain the stuff:

```
result <- data %>% f(arg1=5) %>% g(arg2=0, na.rm=TRUE) %>% h()
```

Where did the first argument go? `%>%` implicitly inserts it into the first argument. (You can insert the preceding result into another argument by referring to it as `.`.